# Using ternary operator inside a condtional gives unexpected output

Tags: c++, operator-precedence, conditional-operator, ternary

I'm trying to understand what the ternary operating is doing to give me this output. I would expect that the conditional would short circuit as soon as *true == false* evaluated to false but the result of *return_value* is true in this code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool return_value = true == false &&
                        true == false &&
                        false ? (true == false) : true; // add parens to see expected output (false ? (true == false) : true);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << return_value << std::endl;

    // expected output: false                                                                                                  
    // actual output  : true
}                                                                                       }
```

If I place parenthesis around the last condition *(false ? (true == false) : true)* then I get the output that I expect.

Is there an order of operations that I am misinterpreting?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence The ternary operator has one of the lowest precedences.  (Lower than `==` and `&&`, which explains the behavior here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the implicit order of operations is

```cpp
bool return_value = (true == false && true == false && false)
                  ? (true == false)
                  : true;
```

Rather than

```cpp
bool return_value = true == false &&
                    true == false &&
                    (false ? (true == false) : true);
```

Comment: Now that you wrote it like that, it should have been really obvious to me. The first operand in the ternary operator is a conditional statement so it includes everything before it.

Answer (score 1):

The initialize of the declaration

```
bool return_value = true == false &&
                    true == false &&
                    false ? (true == false) : true;
```

can be equivalently rewritten like

```
bool return_value = ( true == false && true == false && false ) ? (true == false) 
                                                                : true;
```

As the result of the logical expression evaluates to false then the third (assignmeny-expression) is returned that is `true`.

According to the C++ grammar the conditional operator is defined like

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
```

And this expression

```
true == false && true == false && false
```

is a logical-or-expression that in turn is defined in the C++ grammar like

```
logical-or-expression:
    logical-and-expression
    logical-or-expression || logical-and-expression
```